# French hyphenation in plain TeX - plain TeX for french

Tags: hyphenation, plain-tex, french

I use plain TeX and work in french, how can I load the correct hyphenation patterns?
How can I modify INITEX in order to get a stable "french plain TeX"?
I would prefer not to go to LaTeX for that and keep working with plain TeX.
EFLM

Answer (score 2):

If you are using e-TeX, just write `\uselanguage{french}` (see [`hyph-utf8`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyph-utf8) for details).  The text is taken from the [`blindtext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package.

```
\uselanguage{french}

Qu'est que c'est? C'est une phrase fran\c{c}ais avant le lorem ipsum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis
non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh
lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel,
semper in, velit. Ut porttitor.  Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique
neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum
augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis
sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus,
aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit
amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\bye
```

Comment: I'm using TeX Live and have the same problem for Italian. What's the solution?